# Wrong output in fastercsv? Too many " in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I am implementing in Ruby, and I just want to read in a CSV-file. My CSV looks like :

```
"official_code","username","lastname","firstname","email","Course Groups","password"
"1626","000078sr","LENS","Ser","blab@hogent.be","project1g43","pwd7975"
"7334","000116jd","DE ","Joen","je0116@.hogent.be","project1g08","pwd5259"
"2003","000136bv","VACKE","Bert","hogent.be","project1g18","pwd5908"
"4065","000166cr","ROHÃ¸J","Chrian","chrhogent.be","project1g10","pwd5000"
```

It is made in Excel and set in a CSV-file

But when I do in my application:

```
 FasterCSV.foreach(file.path, {:headers=>true }) do |row|

            @samples[i] = row
      i += 1
    end # do

 if @samples.size > 0
      @headers = @samples[0].headers
    end
```

and in my view I just do:

```
<%= @headers.inspect %>


<ul>
<% @samples.each do |a| %>
<li>
<%= a %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I get:

```
["\"official_code\",\"username\",\"lastname\",\"firstname\",\"email\",\"Course Groups\",\"password\""]

"""1626"",""000078sr"",""ENS"",""Sder"",""san.hogent.be"",""project1g43"",""pwd7975"""
"""7334"",""000116jd"",""DE VOS"",""Jen"",""jeroen.ogent.be"",""project1g08"",""pwd5259"""
"""2003"",""000136bv"",""VYCKE"",""Bet"",""berent.hogent.be"",""project1g18"",""pwd5908"""
"""4065"",""000166cr"",""ROøJ"",""Chstian"",""chr.hogent.be"",""project1g10"",""pwd5000"""
```

So there are way to many " 's. Does someone know what I am doing wrong? It is just like rows only have 1 column. If I do `samples[0].each` I get only 1 item. The whole row and not the columns.

Comment: Why do you want to put the CSV file on a web page? If you just want to pass on the CSV file you can use send_data csv, :type => 'text/csv'

Comment: But it is not really to show, i fill objects with this data. So i have to go in each column for a property. If i do row[0] I get an empty string...

Comment: what web framework are you using?

Comment: btw - fastercsv has made it into the standard library as "csv" in ruby 1.9. May be good to know when/if you are upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference `@samples` you're looking at an array of *rows*, each of which is an array of parsed fields.

So when you use `@samples.each do |a|`, the `a` is a row, and I think you're getting the result of calling `#inspect` on that row.

What happens if you try something like this?

```
options = { :headers=>true, :return_headers => true }
@samples = FasterCSV.read(file.path, options).to_a

if @samples.size > 0
  @headers = @samples.shift 
end
```

You need `:return_headers=>true` if you want to get the actual labels; `:headers=>true` only tells FasterCSV that there are headings - it discards them by default. `FasterCSV.read` gets and parses all the data in one hit, which is simpler than building the array yourself. Note the `to_a` at the end, which forces the result to really be an array - it might make things simpler in the next part.

What happens if you modify the view as follows (use `#join` instead of `#inspect` on the headers and add  a `#join` on the rows)?

```
<%= @headers.join(', ') %>

<ul>
<% @samples.each do |a| %>
<li>
<%= a.join(', ') %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

If that doesn't fix it, hopefully you should at least be further toward understanding what's happening...

Comment: Ok it works now much better. But there is one thing quit strange. The output of samples is :
"1626","0sr","ROS","Sr","sandehogent.be","pt1g43","pwd7975", , , , , ,
What about all these comma's what is wrong with that? thanks already!!

Comment: that is probably because you have empty values in your array

Comment: Yes, the array only has 1 item which is not nil, the first. That's tha whole row.. all te rest are nil. HOw does this come? WHen i remove the "" from my csv everything works fine. But I also want to do it with the ""